# gRPC status code 16 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

I'm setting up an aws appmesh and seeing this error in the logs on each envoy proxy:

```
StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 16, The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details
```

There is an IAM role attached to the compute resource that I host the Proxy on (ECS Fargate) that has the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSAppMeshEnvoyAccess` policy attached per the documentation.

I'm using the aws provided envoy image: `xxxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/aws-appmesh-envoy:v1.15.0.0-prod`

Any help would be appreciated!
Matt

Comment: I think this had to do with my Interface VPC Endpoint, once I used the public one this went away. I still having issues reading from the cloud map: 

`[2020-10-09 15:45:49.112][1][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:93] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 5, No Cloud Map namespace found for serviceName: myapp, namespaceName: mydomain.local.` 

The ECS Task has the ability to streamaggregate resources on * so I'm not sure what permissions I'm missing

Comment: hey @mattfrsn did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I didn't, we end up not using aws appmesh. I'd be interested in hearing your resolution if you figure it out though. I spent a while on this without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @mattfrsn I resolved the issue by switching over service discovery type from AWS Cloud Map to DNS.

I simply entered my namespace name in the DNS config. e.g, `auth.local.demo.app`

I am not sure why App mesh is not able to discover using AWS Cloud Map config since both of them are pointing to the same thing.

FYI I am using internal name nameaspaces and my Envoy version in 1.16. I planning to switch to 17 though.

I resolved this issue by closely following this [AWS App mesh ingress example](https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-examples/tree/main/walkthroughs/howto-ingress-gateway)